# Distributing iOS App on App Store and Enterprise

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution, enterprise-distribution, ios-enterprise

**TLDR :** 
A. Issue in exporting app with Enterprise Cert

> Error : wildcard app id cannot be used to create in house provisioning
>   profiles

B. Right approach to distribute app on Enterprise and AppStore

We have been distributing apps on Apple's AppStore for years, Enterprise is new addition.
– App has Watch App and supports iOS 8+.

What is done so far:
– Two different dev accounts and certificates.
– Separate provisioning profiles on each accounts
– Build Config and Scheme for Enterprise a AppStore
– using Scheme/Config to switch between settings like bundleId, etc.
– Successfully Archive Enterprise Application

**I have NOT created separate info.plist or entitlements (Do I need to?)**

Issue: When I try to export Enterprise Archive, I am getting error

> wildcard app id cannot be used to create in house provisioning
>   profiles<

I do have proper provisioning profiles created. None of them are wildcard, except created by Xcode.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605566/building-app-for-app-store-and-enterprise-distribution), which says needs to create different targets. That is overhead of keeping both the targets in sync.

Question:

```
bool itIsPossible = Can this be achieved with Configuration/Schemes?

if (itIsPossible){
– What else I need to create separate entitlements etc?
}else{
– Do I have to create new target to support Enterprise App?
– Separate Target for Watch and Extension? 
– What else I need to create separately Info.plist, entitlements etc?
}
```

Comment: Have you ensured that all steps in the below link are done? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

Answer (score 4):

## Using Targets

New targets *do* create some overhead (new files must be added to all relevant targets). New targets allow to easily compartmentalize which file goes where, provide a platform for separate `plist` & `config`, Unit Tests, etc.

Remember that **App Store** executable and **Enterprise** executable are two different applications, with different certificates and signatures. (1)

---

**Separate target recommendations** (from an actual product)

- Shared Entitlements
- PROJECT > TARGETS > General > Team > *pick separate teams there*
- < yourTarget >.`xconfig` (optional & handy)
- `.plist` (most likely, but not required)(2)

---

(1) Same can be said about Apple Watch executables
(2) *Separate `plist` allows for runtime magic: single code controlled by resources*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can manage different provisioning profiles, certificates and bundle id using build configuration. Which leaves teams, that I still have to manage manually. I think that is better than managing two targets.

Comment: Can you post a response to your own question with details, for others to leverage on your experience?

Comment: You probably will have differences in the entitlements at some point, I would be interested how to handle those without different targets!

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to do if you can create separate build script for each application. No need to have separate target.

Here is my build script:
    #  Created by Nguyen Tuan on 10/8/14.
    #!/bin/sh

```
AP_NAME="$1"
echo "App name $AP_NAME"
FILE_NAME="$2"
echo "FILE_NAME $FILE_NAME"
SCHEME="$3"
echo "SCHEME $SCHEME"
PROVISIONING_NAME="$4"
echo "provisioning $PROVISIONING_NAME"
BUNDLE_ID="$5"
echo "BUNDLE_ID $BUNDLE_ID"
AP_ICON="$6"
echo "AP_ICON $AP_ICON"
PARENT_FOLDER="$7"
echo "PARENT_FOLDER $PARENT_FOLDER"
CONFIG="$8"
echo "CONFIG $CONFIG"

PROJECT_HOME_DIR="$9"

#Goto working folder
MY_PATH="`dirname \"$0\"`"
cd $MY_PATH
echo "build sh: This is the current working directory: $MY_PATH"
SCRIPT_FOLDER=$(basename "$MY_PATH")

MY_NAME=$(whoami)
echo "Script Folder $SCRIPT_FOLDER"
sudo sh sudo.sh
echo "Global PATH: \n$PATH"

#Go up to Project folder
cd ../../
rm -r -f build/$PARENT_FOLDER

PLIST=$PROJECT_HOME_DIR/Info.plist
echo "Please enter build number"
#BUILD_NUMBER=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$PLIST")
#BUILD_NUMBER=$(expr $BUILD_NUMBER + 1)
BUILD_NUMBER=`git rev-list HEAD --count`
echo "Get provisioning file: UUID + name for $PROVISIONING_NAME"

if test -d ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/; then
    ProfilesDir=~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
else
    ProfilesDir=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles/
fi

array=$(ls "$ProfilesDir")
provi=""
for i in $array; \
do output=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :Name' /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i "$ProfilesDir/${i%%/}") 2>&1); \
echo $output; \
if [ "$output" == "$PROVISIONING_NAME" ]; then provi=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :UUID' /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i "$ProfilesDir/${i%%/}") 2>&1); break; fi;\
done

#echo PROVISIONING_UUID=$provi >> provisioning.properties
echo "selected profile $provi"

/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set CFBundleVersion $BUILD_NUMBER" "$PLIST"
/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set CFBundleIdentifier $BUNDLE_ID" "$PLIST"
xcodebuild -alltargets -configuration "$CONFIG" clean
xcodebuild -scheme $SCHEME PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$BUNDLE_ID ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS="armv7 arm64" PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$provi PRODUCT_NAME="$AP_NAME" ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME=$AP_ICON archive -archivePath "build/$PARENT_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME.xcarchive" 
#xcodebuild -exportArchive  -archivePath "build/$PARENT_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/$PARENT_FOLDER"
#-exportOptionsPlist $PLIST
echo "export ipa file"
rm -r -f build/$PARENT_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME.ipa
sh $MY_PATH/create_ipa.sh build/$PARENT_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME.xcarchive build/$PARENT_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME.ipa
mv build/$PARENT_FOLDER/**You need to change this to your app name**/.ipa build/$PARENT_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME.ipa
rm -r -f $HOME/Dropbox/$FILE_NAME.ipa
cp build/$PARENT_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME.ipa $HOME/Dropbox/$FILE_NAME.ipa

rm -r -f "build/$CONFIG-iphoneos"

echo "copy xcarchive file into organizer"
sh $MY_PATH/copy_resource.sh build/$PARENT_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME.xcarchive $MY_NAME
```

And then create two build command, one for enterprise build and one for app store build, something like this:

```
AP_NAME="ABCD"
FILE_NAME="An App Name"
SCHEME="Scheme for enterprise build"
PROVISIONING_NAME="Expected provisioning profile, what is shown in XCode"
BUNDLE_ID="app bundle Id"
AP_ICON="custom icon if need?"
PARENT_FOLDER="the folder that will contains the build"
CONFIG="Release"

#Goto working folder
MY_PATH="`dirname \"$0\"`"
sh $MY_PATH/build.sh "$AP_NAME" "$FILE_NAME" "$SCHEME" "$PROVISIONING_NAME" "$BUNDLE_ID" "$AP_ICON" "$PARENT_FOLDER" "$CONFIG"
```

In case you need the `copy_resource` script:

```
path=$1
user=$2
echo $path
filename=$(basename "$path")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
now=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
et=`date +%H:%M:%S`
PATH="/Users/$user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/$now"
echo $PATH
/bin/mkdir -p $PATH
PATH=$PATH/$filename$et.$extension
/bin/mv $path $PATH
```

From now on, just run the command and you will see a build either in working folder or in Xcode Organizer

Comment: It depends. My project contains many applications with different settings. I can also reuse the script with minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the provisioning profile is not set correctly.

The easiest way of doing this is to create an additional configuration.

Select the project in the navigator. Then duplicate the **Release** configuration and rename it to **Enterprise Distribution** or **Enterprise Release**.

[image]

Then select your target and go to **Build Settings**. There you can unfold the settings for **Code Signing Identity**, **Provisioning Profile**. You  also need to use a different bundle identifier.

Check what configuration you use in the archive scheme too.

Comment: This is all set up properly. I have different bundle Id's for App, Extension and Watch targets. I am able to archive as well.

Answer (score 0):

We had the error

> Wildcard app id cannot be used to create in house provisioning
>   profiles

We solved it by manually adding a **Distribution** (In House) Provisioning Profile in the Apple Developer Portal...

[image]